# Oracle different procedure speeds on same instance but different schemas (duplicate)

Tags: performance, stored-procedures, oracle11g

We have an Oracle instance with duplicate schemas. Same procedure runs on one schema in 7 secondes but on the copied schema takes more than 7 hours to complete.

We have rebuild the indexes and tables spaces (an in-house tool), it speeds up a little but still hours to complete.
The dbf (data & index) files are the same for both schemas.

After one hour and 30 mn the alert_bdora10.log file contains these new lines

```
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 35514 (LGWR switch)
  Current log# 3 seq# 35514 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\BDORA10\REDO03.LOG
Fri Aug 25 16:08:57 2017
Time drift detected. Please check VKTM trace file for more details.
Fri Aug 25 17:04:44 2017
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 35515
Private strand flush not complete
  Current log# 3 seq# 35514 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\BDORA10\REDO03.LOG
Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 35515 (LGWR switch)
    Current log# 1 seq# 35515 mem# 0: D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\BDORA10\REDO01.LOG
```

I am a little bit lost and don't know where to investigate first.

Sorry I am a noob at Oracle SQL and any help will be welcome
Thanks
Jluc

Answer (score 0):

After removing lines after lines, finally I discovered a filter which is time consuming

```
select brm.loc_id  , cli.cli_nompatr, cli.cli_nom, cli.cli_prenom, cli.cli_datenaiss
from V_BORDMIXTES brm
INNER JOIN BORDSOMENCSLIGNES bel ON bel.bse_id = brm.bse_id
INNER JOIN REVERSIONS rev ON rev.rev_id = bel.rev_id
INNER JOIN CLISANTES cls ON cls.cls_id = rev.cls_id
INNER JOIN CLIENTS cli ON cli.cli_id = cls.cli_id
where brm.brm_id = 39328
and cli.cli_id = 44517   -- If I add this filter clause, the query takes hours, without 55 ms
```